# Why is asking about beliefs within the government off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I asked [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/61433/there-could-be-no-palestine-without-a-strong-israel-is-this-an-actual-idea). It just got closed.

Some users misunderstood the question and thought I was asking to explain the sentence (nonetheless, they wrote some very interesting answers), although the post was about the U. S. politicians using it publicly. I reckon such a question to be objective as the answer would have been: "?? used this phrase in this context in 19??" or "This idea was underlying State Department's act of 19??" (truth be told, if for some reason, it has never been used whatsoever, there would have been a bit more subjective answer telling why the U. S. politicians do not say such things).

So, why has it got closed? How can I get it reopened?

Answer (score 1):

I did not vote to close, but a general issue with a question of this type:

> Why would *someone* say X?

is that it can easily be too broad and thus admit no clear best answer if "someone" isn't even remotely specified. In fact, the 3 answers you've received kinda illustrate this problem as they all propose different explanations, from different "someones" perspectives and in somewhat different contexts (short term political view during some specific negotiations, long-term historical perspective, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

It really should have been closed for a different reason but you are asking for us to make guesses at the motivations of people.

> Questions asking for the internal motivations of people, how specific individuals would behave in hypothetical situations or predictions for future events are off-topic, because answers would be based on speculation and their correctness could not be verified with sources available to the public.

Comment: Sorry, but I believe you didn't quite get the question. There is nothing about motivation in the post, I am just interested in the usage of a sentence.

Comment: If motivation seems to be there, that must have been my *not quite royal* English ;). Shall I somehow edit the post?

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor The beliefs you are asking about are for all purposes the beliefs of the people in government themselves which means you are essentially asking about their beliefs.

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor With your current edit you will have politicians that believe that and some that don't.

Comment: Well, yes, and such a question could be answered the way I've shown in this meta post: "?? used this phrase in this context in 19??" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

A question gets reopened if it collects 5 reopen votes by people who have enough reputation to vote.

Sometimes it makes sense for the author to improve the question in order to address criticisms. Sometimes it's a matter of debate between experienced users whether a question is on-topic or not, it seems to be the case for your question. If the debate cannot be settled, a moderator will make the final decision.

Currently your question has 3 reopen votes.

Comment: Not sure how this answers the question about why it was closed.

Comment: @JoeW my point was just to explain to OP that sometimes on this site people don't agree on whether a question is on-topic or not, that's why a question can be closed and sometimes reopened later depending on the outcome of the debate.